# How do I access an external file for XCTest in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I need my Swift tests to login and I don't want to store the credentials in code. How can I create a struct outside of XCTest or a file that can be parsed by swift so I don't have to hard code the creds? I'm testing on iOS simulators not for a Mac app.

Currently I have it in a struct within the project

```
struct Config {
static let USERNAME = "test@test.com"
static let PASSWORD = "test"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Mock server response so you don't have to use actual credentials?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a .plist file:

```
guard let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "plist"),
    let configuration = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: file) as? [String: Any] 

else {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not taking full credit as I had one of my devs help me write this, but I can explain it and hope this benefits others in the future. Thanks @MXV for the tip

- First create a plist file in your project
- In the plist file add properties and values
- create a dictionary that can takes a string of Any and cast type Dictionary to a var that uses the plist file created

  ```
  var plistDictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>? {
  get {
      guard
          let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "config", ofType: "plist"),
          let configDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
          else { return nil }
      return configDictionary as? Dictionary
  }}
  ```
- Create a function to use the `plistDictionary`

  ```
   func plistValueForKey(_ key:String) -> Any? {
  return plistDictionary?[key] ?? nil
  ```

  }
- In your test script make a call to `plistDictionary` and parse the dictionary object

  ```
  func enterEmail() {
  emailField.tap()
  if let email = self.plistValueForKey("Username") as? String {
      emailField.typeText(email)
  }
  ```